# Using HTTPS or RSA for android's user data upload

Tags: android, encryption, https

Google says that if I want to upload user data (like a list of the user's installed apps), I need to "transmit it using modern cryptography (for example, over HTTPS)". I have a HTTP server, but i'm having problems converting it to HTTPS. Can I instead use RSA or something like it to encrypt the user data?

Please tell me what you think.

Comment: Sure you can, but who knows if this will be enough for Google.

Comment: That's what i'm asking... Do you think it will be enough? Who can I ask?

Comment: The time you spend getting HTTPS to work will be far less than the time you spending writing a custom crypto solution.  In the friendliest way possible, the fact that you only mention RSA shows that you don't really understand what you are doing, so don't roll your own!